# mkdir always creates a file instead a directory

Tags: bash, mkdir

First I want to say that I don't really know what I should look for, here in Stack Overflow and what could be a good query for my problem.

In simple words I want to create a new directory and than do some file operations in it. But with the script that I have crafted I got always a file instead of a directory. It seems to be absolutely regardless how I stick the code together there is always the same result. I hope tat masses can help me with their knowledge.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

 DLURL=http://drubuntu.googlecode.com/git'
 d7dir=/var/www/d7/'
 dfsettings=/var/www/d7/sites/default/default.settings.php
 settings=/var/www/d7/sites/default/settings.php

#settiing up drush
drush -y dl drush --destination=/usr/share;  

#Download and set up drupal
cd /var/www/;
drush -y dl drupal;

mkdir "$d7dir"; #this is the line that always produces a file instead a directory
                # regardless if it is replaced by the variable or entered as         
                # /var/www/d7


cd /var/www/drup*;
cp .htaccess .gitignore "$d7dir";
cp -r * "$d7dir";
cd "$d7dir";

rm -r /var/www/drup*;
mkdir "$d7dir"sites/default/files; 
chmod 777 "$d7dir"sites/default/files;  
cp "$dfsettings" "$settings";
chmod 777 "$settings";
chown $username:www-data /var/www/d7/.htaccess;
wget -O $d7dir"setupsite $DLURL/scripts/setupsite.sh; >  /dev/null 2>&1
chmod +x /var/www/setupsite; 
echo "Login Details following..."; 
read -sn 1 -p "Press any key to continue...";
bash "$d7dir"setupsite;
chown -Rh $username:www-data /var/www;
chmod 644 $d7dir".htaccess;
chmod 644"$settings";
chmod 644"$dfsettings"; 
exit
```

I hope someone got the reason for that.

Comment: Are the single quotes in the end of the first two lines actually in your code? Because if they are then the `d7dir` variable will not be set. Also, you may want to add `set -x` in the beginning of your script, so that you can see some debugging info.

Comment: Is this a copy of the script or did you type it in? There are couple of other problems as well - last two `chmod` need a space after 644, 3rd from last `chmod` needs to have a " before `$d7dir`, wget missing " before `$d7dir`, chmod after wget is wrong (should be `"$d7dir"setupsite`), etc.

Comment: these two single quote are not in the original. Thyre yust from stackoverflow syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to debug a shell-scripting.

- Add `set -x` in your beginning script
- Get the return value.

  ```
  mkdir 'the-directory'
  ret=$?
  if test $ret -eq 0; then
      echo 'Create success.'
  else
      echo 'Failed to create.'
  fi
  ```
- Set to verbose mode `$ mkdir -v 'the-directory'`

Try this command `$ type mkdir`, to checking mkdir command.

Comment: I have added the -v verbose option behind the mkdir and than started bash with sudo bash -x script name. The script runs trough and had worked if i run it normal the result is still a d7 file. This is very mysterious, isn't it?

Comment: Try to create your folder with `$ mkdir -v $folder_name`, please show me output this command `$ type mkdir`

Comment: The same result here. I avoided the bug by create the dir before anything else. For me it seems to be a bug in the gnu coreutiles.  I'm not absolutely sure so I won't post this as bug.